# IE11 transform with multiple functions rotates around the wrong axis

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

I have this relatively simple css "flipping card" effect using transforms and transitions which works fine in most browsers. In IE11 however, the transform seems to be rotating around the wrong axis.

The problem occurs when I combine a `rotateY()` transform-function with another function, such as `scale()` or `translate()`. If I leave the `rotateY()` by itself, it rotates around the Y axis, as it should.

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/martinjansson/a5nnG/10/ and help me find what's causing this.